# Google Tag Manager, AJAX website and big amount of <script>s

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, google-tag-manager

I have a website that uses AJAX. Every page has its own URL, clicking links initiates XHR request which fetches only the content part of the page. Everything works flawlessly.

I need to set up some marketing codes: one of those is Google Analytics.

I felt like Google Tag Manager could be worth trying, so i set up a container there. I wasn't able to set proper GA tracking through GTM using the standard GA provided in GTM (because of the AJAXification).

I've finally set up working solution:

Every content part of website has this script:

```
<script>
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'pageview',
        'page': {
            'path': '/path/to/page',
            'title': 'Title of the page'
        }
    });
</script>
```

(both `path` and `title` are variable of course)

The variables are properly set up in GTM, I have proper Trigger for the custom event `pageview` and I have two custom HTML tags.

The first one is default GA UA code snippet but without any pageviews - it ends with the `ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-xx', 'auto');` part and fires on every page.

The second one is:

```
<script>
  ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'page': {{page.path}},
    'title': {{page.title}}
  });
</script>
```

The tracking works as expected and everything is fine until you press F12 in chrome and you see `<script>` appended to DOM every time you click some page.

I feel that using JavaScript library to insert `<script>` with one JavaScript function call is a little overkill. Unfortunately I could not find any "Custom JS" as a Tag in GTM.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I have the same "problem" with my other marketing tracking code, so GA-only solution would not be enough for me (and I think my GA solution perfectly illustrates what my "problem" is).

I could come up with a hackish solution, having the `ga('send', 'pageview'` code inside a custom variable, which is used as second condition for the custom trigger `pageview`, but without any fireable tag it obviously does not fire so I would still need to inject some HTML (and my tag would be actually hidden inside a variable and I can imagine it would made my GTM container unmaintainable in the long run).

And maybe I'm just nitpicking - are there any real drawbacks in solution which creates few `<script>`s on every page request (those accumulate over time because of the AJAX thing)? How is the browser performance affected? Would you be satisfied with my solution, or would you use some other way? Or am I missing something?

Comment: To me it sounds like the problem is more with how you are appending the script to the page. you could always skip that step and just execute the javascript in the success of the ajax that grabs the new page content.

Comment: Well, of course, without the Google Tag Manager there wouldn't be any problems and we are actually considering it. OTOH I like the way GTM moves all marketing tags out of the application code and I'd prefer continue using it.

Comment: " Unfortunately I could not find any "Custom JS" as a Tag in GTM" - use a custom HTML tag and add script tags.  And if you are using the history API, GTM has listeners for that.

Comment: I'm not sure if I phrased my question wrongly (english is not my native language) or if you misunderstood: I am currently using custom HTML tag with script tags. GTM's listener for history API may provide better functionality for my use case but I think it's off-topic for this question.

Comment: @ne0, your english is fine. I assume I misunderstood the question.